# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" postgresql version 10

Tags: postgresql

I recently installed Postgre version 10 on a linux red hat. I'm trying to configure that psql will prompt a user for password when accessing the database. After changing everything to scram-sha-256. I'm getting this error when accessing psql

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

This is my pg_hba.conf:
[image]

Any idea how can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgres store password **md5** format as default. If you want to change password encryption you have to follow bellow solution:

**P.S: Before start, You have to undo `pg_hba.conf` file authenticate method to `md5`**

1. Edit `postgresql.conf` and change `password_encryption` to

```
password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

2. Restart Postgres service (or reload service)
3. reset the user password

```
# if use psql cli
\password <user>

# If use SQL command
alter user <user> with password '<password>';
```

4. After updating all passwords you should change `pg_hba.conf` authenticate method to **scram-sha-256** and reset service again

---

Reference: [Information about upgrade postgres password authenicate](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-passwords-to-scram)

Comment: Thanks @Pooya, I've been trying some solutions online but yours work. Thanks!

Comment: For step 2 a reload is sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my comment, I am appreciative for tip

Comment: @Pooya No luck here. I'm running pg in a Docker, so I'm passing the password in via env var: "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword". Do I *also* need to go into the container instance and alter the password, every time I start it up? I haven't tried that yet, but man...this scram stuff has been a headache.

Comment: @TsarBomba According to the Postgres image, You can use [POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/14/bullseye/docker-entrypoint.sh#L236) environment for set authenticate method in the Postgres (When init container on first time - without exist postgres filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

I know that something that solved to me was in setting a new password (in CMD) when it was necessary to give a password for **psql** to be recognized:

```
 set PGPASSWORD= #type here the password you want to set
```

After setting, you write the following (for example):

```
psql -h 188.81.81.92 -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
```

where -h stands for host, -U for user, -d for the database root, -p for port, using the postgreSQL language.

In windows, it could happen to outcome a problem: error: connection to server (...), which can be solved by typing:

```
C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin\\psql.exe
```

this is, you open the file **psql.exe** and it will work fine.